# How to modify Numpy array in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a Pandas Dataframe of 1's and 0's converted to an array :
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]

I'm using the following function to amend the array:

```
def regressor(x, param):
    new_array = x
    for i in range(len(new_array)):

        length = len(new_array)
        current = new_array[(length-i)-1]
        previous = new_array[(length-i)-2]

        if current != 0:
            if previous == 0:
                new_array[(length-i)-2] = current*param

    return new_array
```

However, my array is still unchanged. new_array[(length-i)-2] does not seem to actually amend that element of the array.

Could someone tell me what I'm missing?
Thanks

UPDATE: My problem was solved by converting the DataFrame to a pandas.Series and then converting this to a list within the function.

Comment: Maybe your "param" is 0? i've tested your code, the list does change for param != 0. If you print(new_array) inside the function you can see that. Or maybe you are doing something wrong outside the function

Comment: No, it works fine for a normal python array, but remains unchanged when using a Numpy array

Comment: You have to show us the code where the function is called. What is the numpy array? is it x? why would you need new_array = x? Inside the function there is nothing straight up wrong, probably the problem is where you call it.

Comment: new_array = regressor(current_array, 0.9)

I just named it new_array in the function for my own readability

Comment: There is really nothing wrong with that. If you do new_array = regressor(current_array, 0.9) and print(new_array) it will give you the changed array, doesn't matter if it is numpy.array or not. How are you defining the variables new_array and current_array?

Comment: Is `new_array = x` an attempt to preserve the input array?  Are you expecting to return a copy of the input but modified?  This code modifies the input in place instead of returning a truly "new array". So your output will be exactly equal to the input because they are the same object in memory... however it IS being modified.

Comment: I'm converting a Pandas dataframe to a Numpy array first and then applying the function to it. The array comes back unchanged. If I create a regular array and apply the function, it works fine. Could this be a DataFrame conversion issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run your code I get this (for param=2):

```
x = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

def regressor(x, param):
    new_array = x
    for i in range(len(new_array)):

        length = len(new_array)
        current = new_array[(length-i)-1]
        previous = new_array[(length-i)-2]

        if current != 0:
            if previous == 0:
                new_array[(length-i)-2] = current * param

    return new_array

new_array = regressor(x, 2)
print(new_array)
# Output:
# [8, 4, 2, 1, 2097152, 1048576, 524288, 262144, 131072, 65536, 32768, 16384, 8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Why do you not see changes in your `new_array`? Do you actually call the regressor function to update your array?
Also, copying `x` to `new_array` at the beginning of the function is redundant.

Just re-posting your function with some edits for better readability:

```
def regressor(arr, param):
    for i in range(len(arr)):

        length = len(arr)
        current = arr[(length-i)-1]
        previous = arr[(length-i)-2]

        if (current != 0) and (previous == 0):
                arr[(length-i)-2] = current * param

    return arr
```

Comment: Yes this works for a list or normal python array, but it is unchanged when using a Numpy array

Comment: It's the same also with a numpy array:
For `x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])`
 it returns 
`array([      8,       4,       2,       1, 2097152, 1048576,  524288,
        262144,  131072,   65536,   32768,   16384,    8192,    4096,
          2048,    1024,     512,     256,     128,      64,      32,
            16,       8,       4,       2,       1])`

Comment: I wonder if the copy of `x` to `new_array` at the beginning was a failed attempt to preserve the input array `x` instead of modifying it in place.  Otherwise you don't even really need to return it.   I almost bet that @Ferrari_M is saying the array is unchanged because `new_arr` == `x` ... which is true because they are the same object that is getting modified in place.

Comment: I'm converting a Pandas dataframe to a Numpy array first and then applying the function to it. The array comes back unchanged.

If I create a regular array and apply the function, it works fine. Could this be a DataFrame conversion issue?

Comment: UPDATE: My problem was solved by converting the DataFrame to a pandas.Series and then converting this to a list within the function.